# TicTacToe - Return values from MinMax unsaved

Tags: javascript, recursion, minmax

I'm attempting to debug some demo code from the web, so as to understand how board states are stored and minMax works. There are no issues with the accompanying HTML (omitted here for brevity).

With recursive calls to the minMax function, gameState is checked successfully, and copies of the board are generated internally and populated successfully (per the console).

However, the return value, aptly named `value`, is never generated. In fact, the object I'm trying to push onto the `values` array never makes it there, though the recursion occurs. Consequently, the following error is thrown: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'cost' of undefined`.

Any thoughts?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
                const PLAYER = 'O';
                const HAL = 'X';

                let board = [
                    [' ', ' ', ' '],
                    [' ', ' ', ' '],
                    [' ', ' ', ' ']
                ];

                function minMax(newBoard, depth, player) {
                    let gameState = gameWon(newBoard);
                    let boardCopy = _.cloneDeep(newBoard);
                    if (gameState === false) {
                        let values = [];
                        for (let k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                            for (let l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
                                if (boardCopy[k][l] !== ' ') {
                                    continue;
                                }
                                boardCopy[k][l] = player;

                                // value that is not logged                               
                                let value = minMax(boardCopy, depth + 1, (player === PLAYER) ? HAL : PLAYER);
                                values.push({
                                    cost: value,
                                    cell: {
                                        i: k,
                                        j: l
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        if (player === HAL) {

                                // error thrown                            
                                let max = _.maxBy(values, (v) => {
                                return v.cost;
                            });
                            if (depth === 0) {
                                return max.cell;
                            } else {
                                return max.cost;
                            }
                        } else {
                            let min = _.minBy(values, (v) => {
                                return v.cost;
                            });
                            if (depth === 0) {
                                return min.cell;
                            } else {
                                return min.cost;
                            }
                        }
                    } else if (gameState === null) {
                        return 0;
                    } else if (gameState === PLAYER) {
                        return depth - 10;
                    } else if (gameState === HAL) {
                        return 10 - depth;
                    }
                }

                function hal() {
                    return minMax(board, 0, HAL);
                }

            });
```

Comment: That is a lot of code. Can you show us the relevant part i.e where the error occurs?

Comment: Editing now. Was unsure of how much needed to be shown.

Comment: More is usually better.  I see where your recursive call is happening I think your issue is that cost is apart of an array from what I see in a min object and a values array.  Either way you should check to see if it has a value the object or the array before returning it.  Therefore the undefined. Put a break point and verify that you're hitting the 'cost' object when you expect.  Second make sure it has a value (if it doesn't I'd wrap a conditional statement around it to set or skip).